# Writing after alpha symbol and the letters get´s weird

Tags: math-mode, errors

so I´m trying to write a phrase on TexMaker after put the alpha symbol but for some reason the letters start to become weird and don´t have spaces between them.
This is my code:

```
Pretendemos então verificar se, para \alpha = 0.05, existem diferenças significativas entre os valores médio de uma variável quantitativa
```

This is my output:

[image: This is my output:]

There is some way so solve this?

Comment: `$\alpha=0.05$`

Comment: you get an error from this. Don't ignore such errors!

Comment: after any error, the pdf is just a debugging aid, it is not intended to be usable

Comment: Yes it does thanks!